# Remove spaces in string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to remove spaces on before of a strings and also replace all spaces between words to a space. If after string have spaces , please remove all spaces to a space. How can I do that?

Such as:

```
"       My           name   is    Eddy       " -> "My name is Eddy "

"       My           name   is    Eddy" -> "My name is Eddy"
```

Comment: Does trim is not work for you? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HCnnY/). Also [refer](http://www.sitepoint.com/trimming-strings-in-javascript/)

Comment: Why is the space after `Eddy` not removed in the first example?

Comment: @Bergi It's used for my auto complete. I just want to remove the duplicate query to server.

Comment: So you do *not* want to remove spaces after the strings? Please [edit] your question to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want?

```
function removeSpace(string) {
    return string.replace(/\s*([^\s]+\s?)\s*/g, '$1');
}
```

The jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/5EPC8/

Answer (score 2):

Replace multiple occurrences of spaces (`\s+`) with a single space `' '` with the [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, then trim the remaining from the left and right with the [`String.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method.

```
"       My           name   is    Eddy       ".replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim()
```

`trim` is available in FF 3.5+, IE 9+, Safari 9+.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var str=" My name is Eddy ";
alert(str.trim());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SBhg9/)

Try this code also

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

Comment: @user3296015: [Use a modern browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) :-)

Comment: Please check my demo for better understanding

Comment: But I want it to work on IE6+ and it also doesnt work my cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.trim()` on modern browsers (see [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Browser_compatibility)):

```
" My name is Eddy ".trim()
```

will return

```
"My name is Eddy"
```

On IE8 you can use the polyfill suggested in the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility):

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: There's no trim() function in JS.

Comment: On my IE8, there's no trim function :(

Comment: I added a polyfill for IE8

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this, but I find it easiest to understand with three individual replacements:

```
function cleanup( str ) {
    return str
        .replace( / +/g, ' ' )
        .replace( /^ /, '' )
        .replace( / $/, '' );
}

console.log(
    "'" +
    cleanup( "       My           name   is    Eddy       " ) +
    "'"
);
```

Logs:

```
'My name is Eddy'
```

This is compatible with very old browsers as well as new ones.

Edit: So you want to remove all leading spaces, but if there are trailing spaces you want to keep one trailing space, is that right? That's not how you described the problem.

If you look at the `cleanup` function I posted, it should be apparent how to fix it to not remove trailing spaces:

```
function cleanup( str ) {
    return str
        .replace( / +/g, ' ' )
        .replace( /^ /, '' );
}

console.log(
    "'" +
    cleanup( "       My           name   is    Eddy       " ) +
    "'"
);
```

Logs:

```
'My name is Eddy '
```

Comment: @user3296015: Just omit the third replacement